# btrfs change after system upgrade broke apt-btrfs-snapshot

Tags: linux-mint, btrfs

After upgrading (via `apt-get dist-upgrade`) a Mint 14 Linux box to Mint 15, `apt-btrfs-snapshot` seems to have stopped working:

```
18:25:48 [root@galaxy ~]$ apt-btrfs-snapshot list
Sorry, your system lacks support for the snapshot feature
```

Interestingly, the `btrfs` command-line tool doesn't list the snapshots by default either: (it used to before the upgrade)

```
18:25:50 [root@galaxy ~]$ btrfs subvolume list /
ID 270 gen 26538 top level 256 path stuff
```

but with the `-a` flag, it shows all the `apt-btrfs-snapshot` snapshots as well:

```
18:26:29 [root@galaxy ~]$ btrfs subvolume list -a /
ID 256 gen 26613 top level 5 path <FS_TREE>/@
ID 259 gen 26375 top level 5 path <FS_TREE>/@home
ID 270 gen 26538 top level 256 path stuff
ID 271 gen 348 top level 5 path <FS_TREE>/@apt-snapshot-2013-04-17_21:44:30
ID 272 gen 352 top level 5 path <FS_TREE>/@apt-snapshot-2013-04-17_21:46:25
...
ID 458 gen 26322 top level 5 path <FS_TREE>/@apt-snapshot-2013-06-09_15:55:09
```

So I guess my two questions would be:

- What's up with this `<FS_TREE>` stuff?
- Why did `apt-btrfs-snapshot` stop working?

Relevant package versions:

```
ii  btrfs-tools        0.19+2013011
ii  apt-btrfs-snap     0.3.4.1     
ii  linux-image-3.8.0- 3.8.0-23.34
```

Comment: But the `apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't upgrade the whole distribution. It only pulls the new kernel, which must be supported by your _current_ distribution (not the new one). This is by design in Ubuntu and in Mint 14 particularly.

Comment: Well I also changed the relevant files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`  to point to the new Ubuntu and Mint releases

Comment: Last year btrfs suffered changes, IMO this should not be an issue anymore.

Comment: @Braiam I vaguely recall seeing somewhere that a certain version of btrfs (or the tools) broke apt-btrfs-snapshot... If you can track that down, that'd be a good answer for this question.

Comment: @derobert - looks like the asker [handled it himself.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106600/52934)

Comment: this may happen again as it did for me upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10 however, there is a fix mentioned here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-btrfs-snapshot/+bug/1454306